# PageIndex changes but data stays the same

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview, edmx

I have a `GridView` that I bind a list to from data retrieved via edmx. My issue is when I click on pagers, the page changes, and I have debugged and know that it's changing the value, but it always just shows the data from the first page. What am I missing? Oh, and I call `LoadAllRequestsData()` from `Page_Load` in an `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`.

```
<cm:GridControl runat="server" ID="gvAllRequests" DataKeyNames="Number" OnPageIndexChanging="AllRequestsGridViewPageIndexChanging" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No requests to show." >
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="Number" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerId" HeaderText="CustomerId" SortExpression="CustomerId" Visible="False"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer" SortExpression="Customer" Visible="False"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TypeId" HeaderText="TypeId" SortExpression="TypeId" Visible="False"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Note" HeaderText="Note" SortExpression="Note"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestedOn" HeaderText="Requested On" SortExpression="RequestedOn"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestedById" HeaderText="RequestedById" SortExpression="RequestedById" Visible="False" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestedBy" HeaderText="Requested By" SortExpression="RequestedBy" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedOn" HeaderText="Completed On" SortExpression="CompletedOn" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedById" HeaderText="CompletedById" SortExpression="CompletedById" Visible="False"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedBy" HeaderText="Completed By" SortExpression="CompletedBy" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastModifiedOn" HeaderText="LastModified On" SortExpression="LastModifiedOn" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastModifiedById" HeaderText="LastModifiedById" SortExpression="LastModifiedById" Visible="False"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastModifiedBy" HeaderText="LastModified By" SortExpression="LastModifiedBy" />
                                        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsDeleted" HeaderText="IsDeleted" SortExpression="IsDeleted" Visible="False"/>
                                    </Columns>
                                </cm:GridControl>




private void LoadAllRequestsData(string sortExpression = "RequestedOn", SortDirection sortDirection = SortDirection.Descending)
    {
          var db = new CrewManagerEntities();

          var list = db.GetAllRequestsByUserId(_customerId).ToList();

          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression))
          {
              list = list.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortExpression + " " + (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC")).ToList();
              gvAllRequests.SetSort(sortExpression, sortDirection);
          }

          gvAllRequests.DataSource = list;

          gvAllRequests.DataBind();
    }

    protected void AllRequestsGridViewPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
          gvAllRequests.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
          LoadAllRequestsData();
    }
```

**Edit:** So, I tried using SqlDataSource instead of doing call in codebehind and using a list and the paging works. That is fine but I would like to know why the list doesn't work as there may be instances where I need to use a list source. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any code inside LoadAllRequestsData() to filter "list" with your page number. You are only sorting it but not filtering it based on page number....

Comment: But the PageIndexChanging event changes the page index, I then set source, and bind so shouldn’t that be done automatically by setting the page index?

Comment: My mistake.. that should work.. Can you refer to the link and try changing the code in the PageIndexChanging event as mentioned in the link: http://atikpassion.blogspot.hk/2012/07/aspnet-gridview-paging-in-list.html . Not sure if that is exact issue .. but it might help you

Comment: Still the same issue...was really hoping that would work...What's weird is the pager shows "[ 101 to 125 out of 367 records ]" and the page selected changes as well it's just the row data that doesn't..

Comment: try setting to null : gvAllRequests.DataSource = null;gvAllRequests.DataSource = list;

Comment: @jdweng nothing...I also tested sorting and using dropdown to chnage pagesize and that all works, it's literally just the paging that doesn't trigger a change for whatever reason. I don't think it matters, but I also just remembered this is in an UpdatePanel